# HttpURLConnection: Sending 10,000 requests gives "Connection reset"

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I have a simple java program that send 10,000 HTTP requests to a server in parallel threads.

Many of the requests complete with a successful 200 OK response code but some of the requests fail with the following message:

> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset    at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)   at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)    at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)   at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:689)  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:660)    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1324)

My code is :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.*;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;

public class CreateUsers {

        public static void main(String[] args){
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

                for(int i=0; i<10000; i++){
                        final int cnt = i;
                        new Thread("" + i){
                                public void run(){
                                        try {
                                                 String url = "http://myurl.com"; //I use my actual server url here
                                                URL object=new URL(url);
                                                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
                                                con.setDoOutput(true);
                                                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                                                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

                                                JSONObject parent=new JSONObject();
                                                JSONObject all_users=new JSONObject();
                                                all_users.put("user_name", "abc");
                                                all_users.put("email", "test"+cnt+"@test.com");

                                                JSONArray users = new JSONArray();
                                                users.put(all_users);
                                                parent.put("users", users);
                                                OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
                                             os.write(parent.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
                                                os.close();

                                                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                                                System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
                                                System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
con.disconnect();

                                        }
                                        catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

                                }
                        }.start();
                }
        }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Since the answers here point to the fact that my server is aborting the incoming attempts, I would like to know what kind of server tunings I need to do, to be able to simulate 10,000 incoming requests.

My server is a amazon ec2 instance running on ubuntu, apache tomcat 7, 30G RAM, 4 CPUs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're basically conducting a denial-of-service attack on the machine. The webserver cannot handle that many simultaneous connections and must abort some of the incoming attempts.

If you're intending to write such a tool, it appears to be working just fine. Otherwise, please indicate what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: The target server is my server - I am load testing the server with 10K parallel requests. I want my target server to be able to serve each of the 10K write requests. What tunings should I do on that server, to be able to serve these requests, and not reset the connection?

Comment: We know absolutely nothing about the target server. That's an entire class of information you need to provide in your question. If the question is about tuning a server to handle many requests, why would your post only include information about the client test tool?

Comment: I asked that question as a follow up to your answer that the exception is likely due to the webserver aborting connections.

Comment: I am updating the question with the details on my server

Answer (score 1):

If you really send 10.000 requests, I suspect that the server that is handling your requests gives up on some requests because it's too busy or encountered some other exception while processing your request.

Comment: I am load testing my server, hence sending 10K requests. I will be adding more code to the run() function to simulate 10K parallel http requests hitting my server.

Comment: @Ninja : Testing 10k simultaneous connections from a single computer may not be representative of a real world 10k simultaneous connections scenario... Maybe a distributed JMeter test would cut it better ? You could ramp it up slowly to see where does it start to bend